# How can i change the name of facebook page?

Tags: facebook

I need to change the name of my facebook page.
Is it possible? Facebook doesn't allow to do this. But maybe someone had a successful experience?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. Please refer to Facebook’s Help section instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it centers on support for a commercial product. See [Why can't I ask customer service related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a possibility

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible as far as I know, at least not through an API. Refer to the help section at Facebook.